# Import Amount Paid in screen Bill And Adjusment using webservices API in acumatica system

Tags: c#, web-services, acumatica

I need to import value of Amount Paid using webservices to Acumatica ERP System. Please refer to this screenshot below.

[image]

I have already create some codes using Reference Number = "1700000016", DocType = "Bill", VendorRef = "SV-889-JKT-2", VendorID = "V000000030" and Amount Paid = "1,250,000". Please refer to this codes below.

```
   sCon.getLogin(username, password, url, context);
            AP301000Content konten = context.AP301000GetSchema();
            //context.AP301000Clear();
            List<Command> oCmds = new List<Command>();

            //oCmds.Add(konten.Actions.Insert);
            //--------------- adding header transaction -----------------//
            konten.DocumentSummary.Type.Commit = false;
            konten.DocumentSummary.Type.LinkedCommand = null;
            oCmds.Add(new Value { LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentSummary.Type, Value = "Bill" });
            oCmds.Add(new Value { LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentSummary.ReferenceNbr, Value = "0000" });
            oCmds.Add(new Value { LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentSummary.Date, Value = dtDateSV.Text });
            oCmds.Add(new Value { LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentSummary.VendorRef, Value = "SV-889-JKT-2" });
            oCmds.Add(new Value { LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentSummary.Vendor, Value = "V000000030" });

            //-------------- adding detail transaction (Based on values in Data Grid )-------------
            int a = dgvDocDetailSV.Rows.Count;
            for (int x = 0; x < a; x++)
            {
                oCmds.Add(konten.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.NewRow);
                oCmds.Add(new Value { LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentDetails.Branch, Value = dgvDocDetailSV.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value.ToString() });
                oCmds.Add(new Value { LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentDetails.InventoryID, Value = dgvDocDetailSV.Rows[x].Cells[2].Value.ToString() });
                oCmds.Add(new Value { LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentDetails.JobOrderNbr, Value = dgvDocDetailSV.Rows[x].Cells[3].Value.ToString() });
                oCmds.Add(new Value { LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentDetails.Quantity, Value = dgvDocDetailSV.Rows[x].Cells[4].Value.ToString() });
                oCmds.Add(new Value { LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentDetails.UOM, Value = dgvDocDetailSV.Rows[x].Cells[5].Value.ToString() });
                oCmds.Add(new Value { LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentDetails.UnitCost, Value = dgvDocDetailSV.Rows[x].Cells[6].Value.ToString() });
            }
            //------ add document in Applications Tab Menu -------//
            string DocTypePrepayment = "Prepayment";
            string RefNbrPrepayment = "1700000015";
            oCmds.Add(new Key
            {
                ObjectName = konten.Applications.DocTypeDisplayDocType.ObjectName,
                FieldName = konten.Applications.DocTypeDisplayDocType.FieldName,
                Value = DocTypePrepayment
            });
            oCmds.Add(new Key
            {
                ObjectName = konten.Applications.ReferenceNbrDisplayRefNbr.ObjectName,
                FieldName = konten.Applications.ReferenceNbrDisplayRefNbr.FieldName,
                Value = RefNbrPrepayment
            });
            oCmds.Add(new Value { LinkedCommand = konten.Applications.AmountPaid, Value = "1250000" });

            //------ save transaction in acumatica -------//
            oCmds.Add(konten.Actions.Save);
            var result = context.AP301000Submit(oCmds.ToArray());
```

I have an error message after trying to import this data. The error message is "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> PX.Data.PXException: Error #111: An error occurred while processing the field CuryAdjdAmt : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
".
It seems that field CuryAdjdAmt is null, and this field is mapped to AmountPaid field in Application Menu Tab of Acumatica System.

Please give me reference to solve this issue.
Thanks

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue locally - will post update as soon as I have something to share

Comment: it's okay. many thanks for your respon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is an issue with Adjustments data view delegate caused by performance improvements we made for the Bills and Adjustments screen about a year ago. I've forwarded all details to Acumatica engineering team for further investigation.

As a temporary workaround you can implement an extension for the APInvoiceEntry BLC and slightly change delegate of the Adjustments data view:

```
public class APInvoiceEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
{
    [PXCopyPasteHiddenView]
    public PXSelectJoin<APAdjust,
        InnerJoin<APPayment, On<APPayment.docType, Equal<APAdjust.adjgDocType>,
            And<APPayment.refNbr, Equal<APAdjust.adjgRefNbr>>>>> Adjustments;

    public IEnumerable adjustments()
    {
        IEnumerable result;

        bool origIsImport = Base.IsImport;
        Base.IsImport = false;
        try
        {
            result = Base.Adjustments.Select();
        }
        finally
        {
            Base.IsImport = origIsImport;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

With the temporary workaround applied, I was able to update AmountPaid field with following set of commands. Given the level of complexity put into the Adjustments data view (as it has to work with both records retrieved from database and created at runtime), you have to use RowNumber service command when there are more than 1 document in the Applications tab (Screen-Based API commands of the Key type unfortunately will not work to locate record in the Applications tab).

The sample below will send 2 requests to Acumatica API:
- 1st call to export all records from the Applications tab
- by looping though returned array, you can determine what are RowNumbers of records, that require new value set for AmountPaid
- with your 2nd call, you pass RowNumber and assign new value to the AmountPaid field

```
Screen context = new Screen();
context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
context.Url = "http://localhost/AP301000/Soap/AP301000.asmx";
context.Login("admin", "123");

Content billSchema = context.GetSchema();

// 1st call to export all records from the Applications tab
billSchema.DocumentSummary.Type.Commit = false;
billSchema.DocumentSummary.Type.LinkedCommand = null;

var commands = new Command[]
{
    new Value
    {
        Value = "Bill",
        LinkedCommand = billSchema.DocumentSummary.Type
    },
    new Value
    {
        Value = "000927",
        LinkedCommand = billSchema.DocumentSummary.ReferenceNbr
    },
    billSchema.Applications.DocTypeDisplayDocType,
    billSchema.Applications.ReferenceNbrDisplayRefNbr,
    billSchema.Applications.Balance
};
var applications = context.Submit(commands).ToList();
// end of 1st call to export all records from the Applications tab

// 2nd call to set AmountPaid in the Applications tab
var cmds = new List<Command>();
foreach (var application in applications)
{
    cmds.Add(
        new Value
        {
            Value = applications.IndexOf(application).ToString(),
            LinkedCommand = billSchema.Applications.ServiceCommands.RowNumber
        });
    cmds.Add(
        new Value
        {
            Value = application.Applications.Balance.Value,
            LinkedCommand = billSchema.Applications.AmountPaid
        });
}
cmds.Add(billSchema.Actions.Save);
context.Submit(cmds.ToArray());
// end of 2nd call to set AmountPaid in the Applications tab
```

Comment: Thank you for your respon, I have modified APInvoiceEntryExt but I cannot open screen Bill And Adjusment after I modified this BLC.

Comment: This issue is happen in Bill And Adjustmenst's screen only. Actually I can modified AmountPaid without customize APInvoiceEntry. My problem is I cannot import data to AmountPaid field using webservice. But I will try to update my integration code using your reference's code without customize in APInvoiceEntry

Comment: Just to confirm, provided workaround is specifically to resolve issue with import of AmountPaid field via web service. Could you please  check if you have both data view and a delegate declared in your extension (exactly how shown above). I assume you might have troubles opening Bill And Adjusment screen because of StackOverflowException caused by lack of `[PXCopyPasteHiddenView] public PXSelectJoin<APAdjust,
        InnerJoin<APPayment, On<APPayment.docType, Equal<APAdjust.adjgDocType>,
            And<APPayment.refNbr, Equal<APAdjust.adjgRefNbr>>>>> Adjustments;` in your extension class

Comment: I have modified my integration code (to import value in AmountPaid field using webservices), it works, but only for first record have been success inserted, not for the right prepayment ref number. If I have two prepayments row  (prepayment1 and Prepayment2), and I need to pay Bill for the second prepayment (prepayment2), system will insert always in the first record(in prepayment 1), not for the right prepayment (Prepayment2). Is there any other idea to solve this issue ?

Comment: I have modified my codes of my question, maybe if you want to check it.

Comment: Hari, thanks a lot for the update. Given the level of complexity put into the Adjustments data view, it's necessary to use RowNumber service command when there are more than 1 document in the Applications tab (commands of the Key type unfortunately will not work in this scenario) - I've also updated sample in my answer above. Let me know if now everything works as expected.

Comment: Now it works using your updated code. Many thanks for your help. But I have another question, how we ensure this amount paid will be inserted to the correct prepayment and reference number without knows in which row number related to the current prepayment and reference number ?

Comment: With your 1st call I would expect you to export all records from the Applications tab. Then by looping though returned array, you can determine what are RowNumbers of records, which require new value set for AmountPaid. With your 2nd call (which will be pretty close to the sample above), you simply pass RowNumber and assign new value to AmountPaid field.

Comment: I have already implement your suggestion with 1st call and 2nd call. But I have another issue, all my records was duplicate. I mean if vendor 'A' have 3 records of prepayments, when I try to export using webservices I got 12 records with duplicate values. Do you have reference code to provide it ? I have add my code in answer below to export in application, maybe if you want to check it.. thanks

Comment: Hari, please refer to updated sample above showing the correct way to apply 2-call approach to assign AmountPaid for multiple prepayments of a given Bill

Comment: Thanks for your respon Ruslan, it works perfectly. :)