# Different Result in Exporting Records in Application Tab Menu of Bill and Adjustment's screen in Acumatica ERP System

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl, acumatica

I have create some code to export records in Application Tab Menu of Bill and Adjusment's screen. I used this code below to export all records and store to DataGridView :

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    username = Properties.Settings.Default.username;
    password = Properties.Settings.Default.password;
    url = Properties.Settings.Default.url;

    serverDb = Properties.Settings.Default.serverDb;
    dbName = Properties.Settings.Default.dbName;
    userDb = Properties.Settings.Default.userDB;
    passDb = Properties.Settings.Default.passDB;
}


private void btnFindRefNbr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dgvRefNbrPre.Rows.Clear();
   sCon.getLogin(username, password, url, context);
   AP301000Content billSchema2 = context.AP301000GetSchema();
   billSchema2.DocumentSummary.Type.Commit = false;
   billSchema2.DocumentSummary.Type.LinkedCommand = null;
   var command2 = new Command[]
   {
       new Value { Value = "Bill", LinkedCommand = billSchema2.DocumentSummary.Type},
       new Value { Value = "1700020537", LinkedCommand = billSchema2.DocumentSummary.ReferenceNbr},
       billSchema2.Applications.DocTypeDisplayDocType,
       billSchema2.Applications.ReferenceNbrDisplayRefNbr,
       billSchema2.Applications.Balance,
       billSchema2.Applications.AmountPaid
    };
    //var applications = context.AP301000Submit(command2).ToList();
    var applications = context.AP301000Export(command2, null, 0, false, true);
    int rowApp = applications.Count();
    int ab = 0;
    foreach (var data in applications)
    {
        string docTypeApp = data[0].ToString();
        string refNbrApp = data[1].ToString();
        string balanceApp = data[2].ToString();
        string amountPaid = data[3].ToString();

        dgvRefNbrPre.Rows.Add();
        dgvRefNbrPre.Rows[ab].Cells[0].Value = ab.ToString();
        dgvRefNbrPre.Rows[ab].Cells[1].Value = docTypeApp;
        dgvRefNbrPre.Rows[ab].Cells[2].Value = refNbrApp;
        dgvRefNbrPre.Rows[ab].Cells[3].Value = balanceApp;
        dgvRefNbrPre.Rows[ab].Cells[4].Value = amountPaid;
        ab++;
    }
    sCon.getLogout(context);
}

public void getLogin(string username, string password, string url, Screen context)
{

    context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
    context.Timeout = 1000000;
    context.Url = url;
    LoginResult login = context.Login(username, password);
}

public void getLogout(Screen context)
{
    context.Logout();
}
```

this code works fine in my instance of my local PC.
I try to implement the same code above in another instance, and run this code but it doesn't work.

```
     wsdl of instance 1 : http://localhost/SGL2016/(W(1))/Soap/SGLI.asmx,
     wsdl of instance 2 : http://202.182.186.133:82/SGLI/Soap/SGLI.asmx,
     wsdl of instance 3 : http://localhost/AcuSGL/(W(1))/Soap/SGLI.asmx,
```

Only in wsdl of instance 1 has been worked. in wsdl 2 and 3 it didn't work.

Comment: Did you publish on all 3 instances the APInvoiceEntry BLC extension suggested at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41605306/import-amount-paid-in-screen-bill-and-adjusment-using-webservices-api-in-acumati ?

Comment: Sorry cause I forgot to create APINvoiceEntryExt accordance with the advice you have given for every instances, whereas this must be done to achieve the result.

thank you for remind me of it. :)