# Acumatica AP301000GetSchema returns null

Tags: null, acumatica, getschema

Sometimes the AP301000GetSchema  method will return null in the DocumentDetails. I appreciate if someone have a solution.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ScreenSoapClient WsAcumaticaBA = null;
        try
        {
            WsAcumaticaBA = new ScreenSoapClient(new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport) { AllowCookies = true, MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536 * 4 }, new EndpointAddress(@"https://acumatica.xxxx.com/Soap/ACUAPWEBSERVICE.asmx"));
            if (WsAcumaticaBA != null)
            {
                LoginResult AcuLoginResult = WsAcumaticaBA.Login(string.Format("{0}@{1}", "username", "tenant"), "password");
                if (AcuLoginResult != null && AcuLoginResult.Code == ErrorCode.OK)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Code: {0} - Session: {1}", AcuLoginResult.Code, AcuLoginResult.Session));
                        AP301000Content AcuAP301000Content = WsAcumaticaBA.AP301000GetSchema();
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("AcuAP301000Content: {0} - DocumentSummary: {1} - DocumentDetails: {2}", AcuAP301000Content != null ? "OK" : "NULL", AcuAP301000Content.DocumentSummary != null ? "OK" : "NULL", AcuAP301000Content.DocumentDetails != null ? "OK" : "NULL"));
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Sometimes the AcuAP301000Content.DocumentDetails is null.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more information about the Acumatica version you are using? Also you seems to be using the Screen based API, though this seem to me like it is a different way of using it than the one describe in the Acumatica University course. Have you taken a look there?

Comment: Acumatica Version 6.10.0589. we used the service reference instead of the web reference. changed back to web reference and will watch for sometime. but service reference should work

Comment: we are still experiencing the same problem. it is random. we replaced the service reference with the web reference in the Visual Studio.

Comment: 'code'private BA.Screen _WsAcumaticaBA;
protected BA.Screen WsAcumaticaBA
{
get
{
if (this._WsAcumaticaBA == null)
{
this._WsAcumaticaBA = new BA.Screen();
this._WsAcumaticaBA.Url = Settings.AcuBillAdjWSEndPoint;
this._WsAcumaticaBA.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
this._WsAcumaticaBA.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
this._WsAcumaticaBA.EnableDecompression = true;
this._WsAcumaticaBA.Timeout = 1000000;
return this._WsAcumaticaBA;
}
else
return this._WsAcumaticaBA;
}
set { _WsAcumaticaBA = value; }
}

Comment: sometimes it works, other times, DocumentSmmary , DocumentDerails, FinancialDetailsLinkToGL or any field are null when we get the schema with  AcuAP301000Content = this.WsAcumaticaBA.AP301000GetSchema();

Comment: i think similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41605306/import-amount-paid-in-screen-bill-and-adjusment-using-webservices-api-in-acumati